# Android Provider in Dynamic Feature module not found in Base Module

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature, dynamic-delivery

I am using some libraries in my dynamic feature module. These libraries are Adding some providers to the manifest.

For example in my build.gradle file in the dynamic module:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.11.1'
    ...
}
```

This library adds the following tag to the manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider"
        android:authorities="{$applicationId}.imagepicker.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/image_picker_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

The problem is when I build my base module the app crashes because it cannot find the provider. How can I solve this?

As it is stated [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#base_manifest):

> The manifest for your app’s base module is similar to that of any other app module. Keep in mind, when Google Play generates your app’s base APK, it merges manifests for all modules into that of the base APK.

But why only providers are affected? Are activities ignored?

This is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.rashin.mototel-h7B8g42gBcVABkik16vqzw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ir.rashin.mototel-h7B8g42gBcVABkik16vqzw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.rashin.mototel-h7B8g42gBcVABkik16vqzw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ir.rashin.mototel-h7B8g42gBcVABkik16vqzw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:121)
    at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(CoreComponentFactory.java:62)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6380)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: post the complete stacktrace and the code you use to access your provider

Comment: @pskink I posted complete stacktrace. I do not access this provider in my base module. My base module is an empty module for testing only. Just an empty activity for launcher.

Comment: and you are sure you have a class `com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider` in your apk?

Comment: @pskink Sir that class is not in my apk. This class is added by the dependency of the dynamic feature module. But this is added in the manifest of dynamic which is merged with base module's manifest. That is the source of error. because the class is not added in base module's apk but it exists in the manifest.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same one and I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: @FruitAddict I think the only solution as of now would be to add the dependency to the base module. I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: I met same issue Y_Y

Comment: Do you guys have any solution?

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukh Unfortunately no. I gave up a while ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution.

Add provider with `tools:node="remove"` in you app build.gradle

```
<provider
        android:name="com.esafirm.imagepicker.helper.ImagePickerFileProvider"
        android:authorities="{$applicationId}.imagepicker.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:node="remove" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/image_picker_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

In Android Studio it will be marked as red but when you build bundle with

```
./gradlew clean bundleRelease
```

it should finish with success.

Now you can generate .apks file and unzip it:

```
java -jar bundletool-all-0.10.2.jar build-apks --bundle=app.aab --output=release.apks --ks=release.keystore --ks-pass=pass:xxxxxx --ks-key-alias=xxxxxxkey --key-pass=pass:xxxxxx

unzip release.apks
```

After this you can decode your .apk files (for example with apktool) to take a look at their manifests.
Now in base-master.apk you shouldn't see your provider entries, and in {dynamic-module}master.apk it should be available.

```
java -jar apktool_2.4.0.jar d release/splits/base-master.apk
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems like a clever idea. But does it work when the dynamic module is installed?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it works for my dynamic module. Did you try it?

Comment: The base apk is fine, but feature apk is missing provider too so it won't get registered