# Adding WorkManager Worker Factories to a dynamic feature module

Tags: android

Worker factories are used to construct workers for WorkManager on demand (when a task is ready to run). I am using dynamic feature modules: i.e. 2 modules, :app and :feature, where :feature depends on :app, and my worker is in :feature.

To inject a worker, I need to inject its factory class, because Workers are created by android, not us. Therefore, I tried to `DelegatingWorkerFactory` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/DelegatingWorkerFactory) to add more factories to the workManager configuration, but I cannot import the worker (or its factory) since dependencies are reversed in dynamic feature modules (:feature depends on :app): [modified from here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/adssched/shared/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/shared/data/work/IoschedWorkerFactory.kt)

```kotlin
@Singleton
class MyWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(): DelegatingWorkerFactory() {
    init {
      addFactory(Class.forName(FULLY_QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME).getConstructor().newInstance() as WorkerFactory)
    }
}
```

**How do I support workers/ worker factories in dynamic feature modules?** It seems like dynamic feature modules are never available at start up (onCreate). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772461/android-provider-in-dynamic-feature-module-not-found-in-base-module) is a related issue.

---

[WorkManager : How to set-up different WorkManager Configurations in same App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942384/workmanager-how-to-set-up-different-workmanager-configurations-in-same-app) may be relevant to you to gain more context. My existing workaround uses reflection to get the classname instead of `ConferenceDataWorker::class.java.name`, and a bit dissapointed that dynamic feature modules requires it. Reflection is said to be slow by the great Derek Banas.

I am not using Hilt. Also, apparently Hilt doesn't support dynamic feature modules.

Answer (score 0):

After trying reflection and ClassNotFoundExceptions, I have just removed the dynamic feature module, and bundled it with the app. Would still be interested if there is a solution.